# Problema com NPM NodeJS Compass

Tags: node.js, front-end, npm, compass

Estou com um problema aqui com NodeJS.

Primeiro rodo o comando: `npm i`

Depois rodo o comando: `grunt`

Ai dá esse erro:

```
Warning: Couldn't find the `compass.bat` binary. Make sure it's installed and in
 your $PATH Use --force to continue.
```

Comment: tente utilizar o comando ```gem install compass``` antes de rodar os comandos do npm

Comment: Se estás a usar o compass com o Grunt podias usar o https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-compass

Comment: O problema é justamente este. Tenho compass instalado 'npm install -g compass'